# Filtering object based on a list of ordered strings c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling to filter data returned from a service, I've created a dummy example below. Would they be an effective way to select only the fields passed into the method and return them in the same order the strings are in the list.

Method one to return all values:

```
GetAll()
{
    ServiceModelResult result = await GetAllFromDatabase(); 

    return result;
}
```

Method two - we pass in the dynamic list of fields we want to be included in the return model and in the correct order:

```
List<string> fieldsIWantToReturn = new List<string>("FirstName", "CustomerName", "Shop", "ExportPhase")

GetFilteredResults(List<string> fieldsIWantToReturn)
{
    var result = await GetAllFromDatabase();

    //This is the section I don't know how to do.
    var filteredResults =  //do something here to filter - only select the properties defined in the filter class & in the same order

    return filteredResults;
}
```

Comment: What should `GetFilteredResults` return? What type eg. an array, a model, an anonymous class, a dynamic object, a json, a XML?!?

Comment: Why can't you just ignore the populated properties you don't want?

Comment: Are you using any ORM (Entitfy Framework etc.)?
If you are, you can just project a new object by:
var o = dbContext.MyEntities.Select(obj => new { FirstName = obj.FirstName, CustomerName = obj.CustomerName});

Comment: @Metheny - assuming his return type should be an anonymous class. Now he would need how to build it dynamically based on a list of string

Comment: @Rand the use of strings is not type safe, better just project the required properties.

Comment: @Metheny - well with `nameof(Foo.FirstName)` the string could be type safe, but I get your point, but that seems to be OPs requirement

Comment: This should return a dynamic list. Is it best to use reflection to map the strings to properties? At the moment I can't use lambda expressions as I'm using strings and not properties

Comment: @Metheny Yes, I'm using Entity Framework, but I can't hardcode the properties from a list of strings, this also wouldn't be dynamic if the list changed.

Comment: You could build an expression tree (System.Linq.Expressions) from all the strings, and use the expression as a parameter for the Select() method. Then you could probably return the retrieved objects as a list of dynamic objects.

Comment: Check if you can use ExpandoObject for your use case. You need to reflect on the properties of ServiceModelResult object to get only the desired properties and use the ExpandoObject as a dictionary to populate it. This is shown here "https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-c-objects-dynamically". The other option is to you expression tree as Metheny suggested.

Comment: @RandRandom I don't see an anonymous object as meeting the order requirement (whatever that means).

Comment: When you say "dynamic list", do you mean a `List<dynamic>` where each item in the `List` is a single field value from the result?